# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keyCode')

Tags: javascript, jquery

hope doing good , so i'am making POS system , i'am adding product to cart normally i checked that the product is added and the data is good :

````
function addToCart(id, name, origQuantity, price_v, price_v2 = null, price_v3 = null, img, illimited_quantity) {

            // Fetching the updated quantity
            let quantityElement = document.getElementById('product-qty-' + id);
            let quantity = origQuantity; // original quatity

            if (quantityElement) {
                let domQuantity = parseInt(quantityElement.textContent.replace('Qty: ', ''));
                if (domQuantity !== origQuantity) {
                    quantity = domQuantity;
                }
            }
            if (illimited_quantity == 1) {
                
                if (!("id" + id in cart)) {
                    cart['id' + id] = {
                        'id': id,
                        'quantity': 1,
                        'name': name,
                        'price': price_v,
                        'img': img,
                    };

                    let imgurl = '';

                    if (img != '') {
                        imgurl = '/images/product/' + img;
                    } else {
                        imgurl = '/assets/img/product/noimage.png';
                    }

                    let output = `
    <ul class="product-lists">
        <li>
            <div class="productimg">
                <div class="productimgs">
                    <img src="${imgurl}" alt="img">
                </div>
                <div class="productcontet">
                    <h4>${name}</h4>
                    <div class="productlinkset">
                        <h5>#${id}</h5>
                        <div class="increment-decrement">
                                <div class="input-groups">
                                    <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus dec button" onclick="decreaseQuant(this)">
                                    <input type="text" name="child" value="1" class="quantity-field" onchange="updateQuantity(this.value, '${id}', ${quantity})" id="prod_quant_${id}">
                                    <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus inc button " onclick="increaseQuant(this, ${quantity}, ${illimited_quantity})">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>                            </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <select class="select" onchange="updatePrice(this.value, ${id})">
                <option selected value="${price_v}">${price_v} Da</option>
                ${price_v2 != null && price_v2 != '' ? `<option value="${price_v2}">${price_v2} Da</option>` : ''}
                ${price_v3 != null && price_v3 != '' ? `<option value="${price_v3}">${price_v3} Da</option>` : ''}
            </select>
        </li>
        <li><a class="" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteProd($(this), '${id}')"><img src="/assets/img/icons/delete-2.svg" alt="img"></a></li>
    </ul>
`;
                    // append html
                    $('#cart').append(output);
                } else {
                    cart['id' + id].quantity = parseInt(cart['id' + id].quantity) + 1;
                    $('#prod_quant_' + id).val(cart['id' + id].quantity);
                }
            } else {
                if (!("id" + id in cart)) {
                    if (quantity == 0) {
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Erreur',
                            'Repture stock!',
                            'error'
                        );

                        return;
                    }
                    cart['id' + id] = {
                        'id': id,
                        'quantity': 1,
                        'name': name,
                        'price': price_v,
                        'img': img,
                    };

                    let imgurl = '';

                    if (img != '') {
                        imgurl = '/images/product/' + img;
                    } else {
                        imgurl = '/assets/img/product/noimage.png';
                    }

                    let output = `
    <div class="order-details-wrapper mb-2">
        <div class="left-details">
            <div class="order-img widget-hover"><img src="${imgurl}" alt="${name}"></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="category-details">
            <div class="order-details-right">
                <h6 class="f-14 f-w-500 mb-3">${name}</h6>
                <div class="last-order-detail">
                    <!-- Replace the price display with a select dropdown -->
                    <select class="price-select" onchange="updatePrice(this.value, ${id})">
                        <option value="${price_v}">${price_v} Da</option>
                        ${price_v2 != null && price_v2 != '' ? `<option value="${price_v2}">${price_v2} Da</option>` : ''}
                        ${price_v3 != null && price_v3 != '' ? `<option value="${price_v3}">${price_v3} Da</option>` : ''}
                    </select>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteProd(${id})"><i class="fa fa-trash trash-remove"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-details">
                <div class="touchspin-wrapper">
                    <button class="decrement-touchspin btn-touchspin" onclick="decreaseQuant(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus text-gray"></i></button>
                    <input class="input-touchspin" type="number" value="1" onchange="updateQuantity(this.value, '${id}')" id="prod_quant_${id}">
                    <button class="increment-touchspin btn-touchspin" onclick="increaseQuant(this, ${quantity})"><i class="fa fa-plus text-gray"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`;

                    // Append the HTML
                    $('#cart').append(output);


                } else {
                    // check if max quantity reached
                    if ((cart['id' + id].quantity + 1) > quantity) {
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Erreur',
                            'Max Quantité',
                            'error'
                        );
                    } else {
                        cart['id' + id].quantity = parseInt(cart['id' + id].quantity) + 1;
                        $('#prod_quant_' + id).val(cart['id' + id].quantity);
                    }
                }
            }
            calculTotal();
            $('input[placeholder="SKU / Nom produit"]').val('');

        }
```

when the product is added i'am checking the sale and updating the price and quantity :


```
function checkSale() {
            // check if cart is empty
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(cart)) {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Erreur',
                    'Cart empty!',
                    'error'
                );
                return;
            }

            // Check each item's quantity in the cart to ensure it's not below the stock level
            for (const [key, item] of Object.entries(cart)) {
                if (!updateProductQuantity(item.id, item.name, item.quantity)) {
                    // Stop the sale or handle this error further as the quantity went negative
                    return;
                }
            }


            updateCheckoutPrice();

            if ($('#client_select').val() == 0) {
                addSale();
            } else {
                // get client infos (credit)
                const url = '/pos/client/' + $('#client_select').val();
                $.get(url, function(data, status) {
                    if (status == 'success') {
                        // set it in modal
                        $('#modal_client_fullname').text(data.fullname);
                        $('#modal_client_credit').text(data.credit + ' Da');

                        // show modal
                        $('#sellModalTrigger').click();
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Erreur',
                            'Client not found!',
                            'error'
                        );
                    }
                });
            }
        }
````

then i'am adding the sale :

```
function addSale() {
            // check if cart is empty
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(cart)) {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Erreur',
                    'Cart empty!',
                    'error'
                );
                return;
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('pos.sale.store') }}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    _token: '{{ @csrf_token() }}',
                    cart: $('#cart'),
                    client: $('#client_select').val(),
                    paid: $('#paid').val(),
                    discount: $('#discount').val(),
                    new_total: $('#new_total_input').val()
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    // show loader
                    $("#global-loader").fadeIn("slow");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // hide loader
                    $("#global-loader").fadeOut("slow");

                    Swal.fire(
                        'Erreur',
                        'veuillez réessayer de nouveau',
                        'error'
                    );
                },
                success: function(data, status) {
                    // hide loader
                    $("#global-loader").fadeOut("slow");

                    // print invoice
                    $.print(data);
                    $.print(data);


                    // reloading products
                    reloadProducts();

                    // emptying cart
                    $('#cart').html('');
                    cart = {};

                    // recalcul total
                    calculTotal();

                    // close modal
                    $("#sellModal .close").click();
                }
            });
        }
```

when i click on the button place order :

```
  <div class="place-order">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
 onclick="checkSale()">Sell</button>
```

it say : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keyCode')

and in console its  referencing to script.js file :

```
/*! -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Template Name: Cuba Admin
    Template URI: http://admin.pixelstrap.com/cuba/theme
    Description: This is Admin theme
    Author: Pixelstrap
    Author URI: https://themeforest.net/user/pixelstrap

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        01. password show hide
        02. Background Image js
        03. sidebar filter
        04. Language js
        05. Translate js

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

(function ($) {
  "use strict";
  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
    var outside_space = $(".outside");
    if (
      !outside_space.is(e.target) &&
      outside_space.has(e.target).length === 0
    ) {
      $(".menu-to-be-close").removeClass("d-block");
      $(".menu-to-be-close").css("display", "none");
    }
  });

  $(".prooduct-details-box .close").on("click", function (e) {
    var tets = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass("d-none");
    console.log(tets);
  });

  if ($(".page-wrapper").hasClass("horizontal-wrapper")) {
    $(".sidebar-list").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).addClass("hoverd");
      },
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hoverd");
      }
    );
    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() < 600) {
        $(".sidebar-list").removeClass("hoverd");
      }
    });
  }

  /*----------------------------------------
     password show hide
     ----------------------------------------*/
  $(".show-hide").show();
  $(".show-hide span").addClass("show");

  $(".show-hide span").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
      $('input[name="login[password]"]').attr("type", "text");
      $(this).removeClass("show");
    } else {
      $('input[name="login[password]"]').attr("type", "password");
      $(this).addClass("show");
    }
  });
  $('form button[type="submit"]').on("click", function () {
    $(".show-hide span").addClass("show");
    $(".show-hide")
      .parent()
      .find('input[name="login[password]"]')
      .attr("type", "password");
  });

  /*=====================
      02. Background Image js
      ==========================*/
  $(".bg-center").parent().addClass("b-center");
  $(".bg-img-cover").parent().addClass("bg-size");
  $(".bg-img-cover").each(function () {
    var el = $(this),
      src = el.attr("src"),
      parent = el.parent();
    parent.css({
      "background-image": "url(" + src + ")",
      "background-size": "cover",
      "background-position": "center",
      display: "block",
    });
    el.hide();
  });

  $(".mega-menu-container").css("display", "none");
  $(".header-search").click(function () {
    $(".search-full").addClass("open");
  });
  $(".close-search").click(function () {
    $(".search-full").removeClass("open");
    $("body").removeClass("offcanvas");
  });
  $(".mobile-toggle").click(function () {
    $(".nav-menus").toggleClass("open");
  });
  $(".mobile-toggle-left").click(function () {
    $(".left-header").toggleClass("open");
  });
  $(".bookmark-search").click(function () {
    $(".form-control-search").toggleClass("open");
  });
  $(".filter-toggle").click(function () {
    $(".product-sidebar").toggleClass("open");
  });
  $(".toggle-data").click(function () {
    $(".product-wrapper").toggleClass("sidebaron");
  });
  $(".form-control-search input").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.target.value) {
      $(".page-wrapper").addClass("offcanvas-bookmark");
    } else {
      $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("offcanvas-bookmark");
    }
  });
  $(".search-full input").keyup(function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value) {
      $("body").addClass("offcanvas");
    } else {
      $("body").removeClass("offcanvas");
    }
  });

  $("body").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      $(".search-full input").val("");
      $(".form-control-search input").val("");
      $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("offcanvas-bookmark");
      $(".search-full").removeClass("open");
      $(".search-form .form-control-search").removeClass("open");
      $("body").removeClass("offcanvas");
    }
  });
  $(".mode").on("click", function () {
    const bodyModeDark = $("body").hasClass("dark-only");

    if (!bodyModeDark) {
      $(".mode").addClass("active");
      localStorage.setItem("mode-cuba", "dark-only");
      $("body").addClass("dark-only");
      $("body").removeClass("light");
    }
    if (bodyModeDark) {
      $(".mode").removeClass("active");
      localStorage.setItem("mode-cuba", "light");
      $("body").removeClass("dark-only");
      $("body").addClass("light");
    }
  });
  $("body").addClass(
    localStorage.getItem("mode-cuba")
      ? localStorage.getItem("mode-cuba")
      : "light"
  );
  $(".mode").addClass(
    localStorage.getItem("mode-cuba") === "dark-only" ? "active" : " "
  );

  // sidebar filter
  $(".md-sidebar .md-sidebar-toggle ").on("click", function (e) {
    $(".md-sidebar .md-sidebar-aside ").toggleClass("open");
  });

  $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $(this).remove();
  });

  $(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
      $(".tap-top").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(".tap-top").fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $(".tap-top").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate(
      {
        scrollTop: 0,
      },
      600
    );
    return false;
  });
  (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    var $ripple = $(".js-ripple");
    $ripple.on("click.ui.ripple", function (e) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var $offset = $this.parent().offset();
      var $circle = $this.find(".c-ripple__circle");
      var x = e.pageX - $offset.left;
      var y = e.pageY - $offset.top;
      $circle.css({
        top: y + "px",
        left: x + "px",
      });
      $this.addClass("is-active");
    });
    $ripple.on(
      "animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd",
      function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass("is-active");
      }
    );
  })(jQuery, window, document);

  // active link

  $(".chat-menu-icons .toogle-bar").click(function () {
    $(".chat-menu").toggleClass("show");
  });

  // Language
  var tnum = "en";

  $(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("primary") != null) {
      var primary_val = localStorage.getItem("primary");
      $("#ColorPicker1").val(primary_val);
      var secondary_val = localStorage.getItem("secondary");
      $("#ColorPicker2").val(secondary_val);
    }

    $(document).click(function (e) {
      $(".translate_wrapper, .more_lang").removeClass("active");
    });
    $(".translate_wrapper .current_lang").click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");

      setTimeout(function () {
        $(".more_lang").toggleClass("active");
      }, 5);
    });

    /*TRANSLATE*/
    translate(tnum);

    $(".more_lang .lang").click(function () {
      $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
      $(".more_lang").removeClass("active");

      var i = $(this).find("i").attr("class");
      var lang = $(this).attr("data-value");
      var tnum = lang;
      translate(tnum);

      $(".current_lang .lang-txt").text(lang);
      $(".current_lang i").attr("class", i);
    });
  });

  function translate(tnum) {
    $(".lan-1").text(trans[0][tnum]);
    $(".lan-2").text(trans[1][tnum]);
    $(".lan-3").text(trans[2][tnum]);
    $(".lan-4").text(trans[3][tnum]);
    $(".lan-5").text(trans[4][tnum]);
    $(".lan-6").text(trans[5][tnum]);
    $(".lan-7").text(trans[6][tnum]);
    $(".lan-8").text(trans[7][tnum]);
    $(".lan-9").text(trans[8][tnum]);
  }

  var trans = [
    {
      en: "General",
      pt: "Geral",
      es: "Generalo",
      fr: "GÃ©nÃ©rale",
      de: "Generel",
      cn: "ä¸€èˆ¬",
      ae: "Ø­Ø¬Ù†Ø±Ø§Ù„ Ù„ÙˆØ§Ø¡",
    },
    {
      en: "Dashboards,widgets & layout.",
      pt: "PainÃ©is, widgets e layout.",
      es: "Paneloj, fenestraÄµoj kaj aranÄo.",
      fr: "Tableaux de bord, widgets et mise en page.",
      de: "Dashboards, widgets en lay-out.",
      cn: "ä»ªè¡¨æ¿ï¼Œå°å·¥å…·å’Œå¸ƒå±€ã€‚",
      ae: "Ù„ÙˆØ­Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø¹Ù„ÙˆÙ…Ø§Øª ÙˆØ§Ù„Ø£Ø¯ÙˆØ§Øª ÙˆØ§Ù„ØªØ®Ø·ÙŠØ·.",
    },
    {
      en: "Dashboards",
      pt: "PainÃ©is",
      es: "Paneloj",
      fr: "Tableaux",
      de: "Dashboards",
      cn: " ä»ªè¡¨æ¿ ",
      ae: "ÙˆØ­Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„Ù‚ÙŠØ§Ø¯Ø© ",
    },
    {
      en: "Default",
      pt: "PadrÃ£o",
      es: "Vaikimisi",
      fr: "DÃ©faut",
      de: "Standaard",
      cn: "é›»å­å•†å‹™",
      ae: "ÙˆØ¥ÙØªØ±Ø§Ø¶ÙŠ",
    },
    {
      en: "Ecommerce",
      pt: "ComÃ©rcio eletrÃ´nico",
      es: "Komerco",
      fr: "Commerce Ã©lectronique",
      de: "E-commerce",
      cn: "é›»å­å•†å‹™",
      ae: "ÙˆØ§Ù„ØªØ¬Ø§Ø±Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠØ©",
    },
    {
      en: "Widgets",
      pt: "Ferramenta",
      es: "Vidin",
      fr: "Widgets",
      de: "Widgets",
      cn: "å°éƒ¨ä»¶",
      ae: "ÙˆØ§Ù„Ø­Ø§Ø¬ÙŠØ§Øª",
    },
    {
      en: "Page layout",
      pt: "Layout da pÃ¡gina",
      es: "PaÄa aranÄo",
      fr: "Tableaux",
      de: "Mise en page",
      cn: "é é¢ä½ˆå±€",
      ae: "ÙˆØªØ®Ø·ÙŠØ· Ø§Ù„ØµÙØ­Ø©",
    },
    {
      en: "Applications",
      pt: "FormulÃ¡rios",
      es: "Aplikoj",
      fr: "Applications",
      de: "Toepassingen",
      cn: "æ‡‰ç”¨é ˜åŸŸ",
      ae: "ÙˆØ§Ù„ØªØ·Ø¨ÙŠÙ‚Ø§Øª",
    },
    {
      en: "Ready to use Apps",
      pt: "Pronto para usar aplicativos",
      es: "Preta uzi Apps",
      fr: " Applications prÃªtes Ã  lemploi ",
      de: "Klaar om apps te gebruiken",
      cn: "ä»ªè¡¨æ¿",
      ae: "Ø¬Ø§Ù‡Ø² Ù„Ø§Ø³ØªØ®Ø¯Ø§Ù… Ø§Ù„ØªØ·Ø¨ÙŠÙ‚Ø§Øª",
    },
  ];

  $(".mobile-title svg").click(function () {
    $(".header-mega").toggleClass("d-block");
  });

  $(".onhover-dropdown").on("click", function () {
    $(this).children(".onhover-show-div").toggleClass("active");
  });

  $("#flip-btn").click(function () {
    $(".flip-card-inner").addClass("flipped");
  });

  $("#flip-back").click(function () {
    $(".flip-card-inner").removeClass("flipped");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

here exactly :

```
$("body").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      $(".search-full input").val("");
      $(".form-control-search input").val("");
      $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("offcanvas-bookmark");
      $(".search-full").removeClass("open");
      $(".search-form .form-control-search").removeClass("open");
      $("body").removeClass("offcanvas");
    }
```

i dont have any use of keycode in my sale function , i dont know even why its  referencing to this ,
can someone have an idea , thank you very much

I tried to search a reference between script.js and my two function but no hope , i tried to change that block of code in js like this to check for keycode :

```
$("body").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e && e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(".search-full input").val("");
        $(".form-control-search input").val("");
        $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("offcanvas-bookmark");
        $(".search-full").removeClass("open");
        $(".search-form .form-control-search").removeClass("open");
        $("body").removeClass("offcanvas");
    }
});
```

it goes from keycode error to undefined 'type'

Comment: Know that `keyCode` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), most browsers may have moved away from the use by now ... try `e.key` instead. Check [this site](https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode) for demo usage.

Comment: the probleme is in Addsale i'am not triggring any keycode i dont know why its telling me that

Comment: The `keydown` is applied to the entire body, so any typing within that area will trigger the event?

Comment: Yes but  the error happen only within Addsale ....

Comment: Then before the keyCode check, add a `console.log(e.target)` to see what is getting there, and depending on what it is, then add another condition check to avoid the issue. I wonder if the sweetalert events may be propagating, if those are firing?

Comment: i did a console.log and the output is undefined , and no the sweetalert are not firing

Comment: Ok, if the log of `e.target` is undefined, then what do you get from `console.log(e)`?

Comment: same undefined too